# How to define an aggregated ICollection<T> where T is type of the current declaring class within a hierarchy?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, collections, generic-constraints

I need to inherit a collection of items of the current type, like this

```
class A {
    // some properties...

    public ICollection<A> Children;
}

class B: A {
    // other properties
}
```

This mostly works as expected. The problem is I can do something like this

```
class C: A { }

B b = new B();
b.Children = new List<C>();
```

Is there any way to force `b.Children` to be a collection of `B`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reflexive type parameter constraints:  X<T> where T : X<T> ‒ any simpler alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866071/reflexive-type-parameter-constraints-xt-where-t-xt-any-simpler-alterna)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do such thing yet.

- The C# language has no artifact to declare such thing:

  ```
  class A
  {
    public ICollection<T> Children where T : thisdeclaring;
  }
  ```

  Where `thisdeclaring` represents the current declaring type.
- C# does not support true polymorphism on open types using the diamond operator `<>`

  [How to create List of open generic type of class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948/how-to-create-list-of-open-generic-type-of-classt/58571001#58571001)

  [How to do generic polymorphism on open types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247604/how-to-do-generic-polymorphism-on-open-types-in-c/58247676#58247676)

**Solution 1 : type checking hack on the non generic type**

We check the type at runtime to throw an exeption in case of mismatch, but we must lost the genericity as explained in previous links:

```
using System.Reflexion;

class A
{
  private ICollection _Children;
  public ICollection Children
  {
    get => _Children;
    set
    {
      if ( value == null )
      {
        _Children = null;
        return;
      }
      var genargs = value.GetType().GenericTypeArguments;
      if (genargs.Length != 1 || this.GetType() != genargs[0] )
      {
        string msg = $"Type of new {nameof(Children)} items must be {this.GetType().Name}: "
                   + $"{ genargs[0].Name} provided.";
        throw new TypeAccessException(msg);
      }
      _Children = value;
    }
  }
}
```

*Test*

```
var a = new A();
trycatch(() => a.Children = new List<A>());
trycatch(() => a.Children = new List<B>());
Console.WriteLine();
var b = new B();
trycatch(() => b.Children = new List<A>());
trycatch(() => b.Children = new List<B>());
void trycatch(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action();
    Console.WriteLine("ok");
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

*Output*

```html
ok
Type of new Children items must be A: B provided.

Type of new Children items must be B: A provided.
ok
```

So we can't have the generic type parameter on the collection and the hierarchical type contrainst at the same time, as I know, for the moment.

**Solution 2 : the same hack using dynamic to keep genericity**

```
private dynamic _Children;
public dynamic Children
```

```
  set
  {
    if ( value == null )
    {
      _Children = null;
      return;
    }
    bool isValid = false;
    foreach ( Type type in value.GetType().GetInterfaces() )
      if ( type.IsGenericType )
        if ( type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>) )
        {
          isValid = true;
          break;
        }
    if ( !isValid )
    {
      string msg = $"{nameof(Children)} must be a ICollection of {this.GetType().Name}: "
                 + $"{value.GetType().Name} provided.";
      throw new TypeAccessException(msg);
    }
    var genargs = value.GetType().GenericTypeArguments;
    if ( genargs.Length != 1 || this.GetType() != genargs[0] )
    {
      string msg = $"Type of new {nameof(Children)} items must be {this.GetType().Name}: "
                 + $"{ genargs[0].Name} provided.";
      throw new TypeAccessException(msg);
    }
    _Children = value;
  }
}
```

Here we keep the generic closed constructed type of the collection.

Thus we can use all generic members of the stored instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but with a caveat.

You define the class like this:

```
public class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    public ICollection<T> Children;
}
```

Now you can inherit it to make the class you're looking for:

```
public class B : A<B>
{ }
```

This allows this code to work:

```
B b = new B();
ICollection<B> children = b.Children;
```

The caveat is that the language doesn't enforce you to do the right thing.

You could, instead, do this:

```
public class C : A<B>
{ }
```

That is legal but breaks the contract you're looking for. So it just becomes an exercise in making sure you implement your classes correctly.